# Django: Including standard User table as foreign key in my models?

Tags: python, django

I am designing a Django 1.8 application in which I have the concept of trials and assessors. I will have six assessors, who will use the Django admin to log in and make assessments.

I want each trial to have two attached assessors. How can I use the Django User model in models.py to ensure that the assessors are Users, and can be managed using the full power of Users?

Right now I have this, in which the assessors are not Users, but are just ordinary models:

```
class Assessor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Trial(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=800)
    publication_date = models.DateField()
    first_assessor = models.ForeignKey(assessor)
    second_assessor = models.ForeignKey(assessor)
```

I want the assessors to be Users, so that I can manage them in the usual way through the User tables, but I don't know how to make this change.

They probably don't need any custom fields on top of the standard User attributes.

(NB: I don't need full-on permissions management within the admin, it's OK for any assessor to be able to edit the trial.)

UPDATE: Apologies, this is rather hard to explain! I don't care about the Django front-end at all, only the admin. I want a user to be able to log into the admin, see all the trials on which they are a primary assessor, and edit those trials. I'm not sure if it's best to do this with the User model, or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of two foreign keys add a manytomany relation from Trail to user. Later, if you want you can add more assessors to a trail.

You can do like:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class Trial(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=800)
    publication_date = models.DateField()
    assessors = models.ManyToManyField(User,related_name="trials")
```

You can add assessors to Trial like:

```
trial = Trial.objects.get(id=give-trial-id)
user = User.objects.get(id=give-assessor-id)
trail.assessors.add(user)
```

You can get more info about manytomany [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9574788/filter-django-admin-by-logged-in-user)

I just saw your **UPDATE**. Any one who logs in to admin will have access to all objects of all models.
In your case all assessors who login to admin will have access to all trails irrespective of they are assigned to it or not.

If you want Filter django admin by logged in user then refer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9574788/filter-django-admin-by-logged-in-user)