# Django admin : show records for respective user only

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-queryset

I have a simple model, say Resources. And I have fewer than 20 users and model admin serves the purpose to record requests.

Problem is that all users can see all records in model admin site.

Can this behaviour be changed to only show records created by same user only ?

Thank you in anticipation.

Comment: that's the point of the admin site, superusers can see anything. If you want each user to see only specific items, then I'd recommend you create a separate template for this. Could this apply to your use-case?

Comment: Thanks, do you mean to say - create views with queryset to filter by user and then render template ? I could do that, might take me 2-3 days since I am beginner. I thought if admin site could have this function.

Comment: You can use a generic ListView class-based view and override the `get_queryset()` method provided (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview). Then in the template, just iterate the context data and present them in your template as needed.

Comment: Looks like advanced topics, thanks. I'll try.

Comment: Thinking if get_queryset method (or similar) can be overridden for my model to filter for loggedon user only ..

Comment: No, not at all, don't be afraid of class-based views! I'll also suggest you another approach which should be simpler for you: create a view method, distinguish the user object from the request like this `user = self.request.user` and then build a queryset against your model using this user object. The template iteration part of the queryset remains the same. How does that sound to you?

Comment: Yes I get the flow, almost. And then how do I connect this to the login page please.

Comment: This looks like interesting post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9574788/filter-django-admin-by-logged-in-user

Comment: Well, you can try it, but then how will a superuser actually see all of the data? In any case this is your decision, I am just posting questions here to prevent any time lost in the wrong direction :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The django doc has an example that does almost exactly what you want:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_queryset

The idea is to override the `get_queryset()` method in the model admin view:

```
# admin.py
from django.contrib import admin

class YourModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(MyModelAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        return qs.filter(author=request.user)

admin.site.register(YourModel, YourModelAdmin)
```

You can adapt the queryset filter to even more specific needs at will.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE 2020:**
Anyone who is curious as to what is the author field, then that is established in the `models.py` file of your app. For the `admin.py` part, you can visit the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/).

**Step 1:**

Make sure in your permissions you give access to the apps you want your users to have CRUD functionality over.

**Step 2:**

Admin.py

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super().get_queryset(request)
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return qs
        return qs.filter(author=request.user)
```

Models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

class Lecture(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```